# Select statement in cases with sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

We are implementing a workflow engine with SQLAlchemy.
Two tables in our model are:

```
class DbAttribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "db_dbattribute"
    id  = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    dbnode_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('db_dbnode.id'))
    key = Column(String(255))
    datatype = Column(String(10))
    tval = Column(String, default='')
    fval = Column(Float, default=None, nullable=True)
    ival = Column(Integer, default=None, nullable=True)
    bval = Column(Boolean, default=None, nullable=True)
    dval = Column(DateTime, default=None, nullable=True)
class DbNode(Base):
    __tablename__ = "db_dbnode"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid_func)
    type = Column(String(255), index=True)
    label = Column(String(255), index=True, nullable=True)
    description = Column(Text(), nullable=True)
    ctime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=timezone.now)
    mtime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=timezone.now)
```

Attributes are related to a Node via the dbnode_id foreign key.
I am now working on a query that would return an attribute value (for example tval) and None if this row does not exists because the key is not the right one. This is working on aliased classes now:

```
select_stmt =select([aliased_attributes.tval]).select_from(
         aliased_attributes
    ).where(and_(
        aliased_attributes.key==attrkey,
        aliased_attributes.dbnode_id==aliased_node.id
    ))
exists_stmt = exists(select_stmt)

entity = case([
    (
        exists_stmt,
        select_stmt
   ),
   (
        text('true'), 
        None
   )
])
```

This exits now with the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "SELECT"

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.0.12 and postgresql 9.4.
Any help on what I missed or other ways this could be done better are greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use simple `outerjoin`?

```
attrkey = 'my_attr_key'

q = (
    session
    .query(
        DbNode.label,
        DbAttribute.tval,
    )
    .outerjoin(
        DbAttribute,
        and_(
            DbAttribute.dbnode_id == DbNode.id,
            DbAttribute.key == attrkey,
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot van. A simple outerjoin (like your solution) works fine in simple cases. But if you have to join many entities of DbNode together,  the projection of an attribute has to become a subquery. That is what I am struggling with. I should have been more specific about that, sorry

Comment: @nikka: you can perform multiple joins as well. You just need to use aliases. See [Using Aliases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a shot!